# Go back after call Intent.ACTION_VIEW in android and then Resume (Deep linking)

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

In my application there is a feature through which user can share a link and by clicking on the link application will start. (Deep Links to App Content)

In my MainActivity class there is a method named `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` which will called when it opens through the link.

Now i clicked the link, it open my application MainActivity class, `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` has been called. After that i pressed back button and close the application. now tap on the running task button of the app and open app through it. It will again called `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` **Intent.ACTION_VIEW** instead of **Intent.ACTION_MAIN**.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the `launchMode` fro this `Activity` in Manifest ?  Have you called `setIntent()` inside `onNewIntent` ?

Comment: 'android:launchMode="singleTask"', and there is no 'setIntent()' inside 'onNewIntent'.